# PHP Convert A File to JPG

Tags: php, gd

Currently, I learn about File To image encryption

first, I upload a file, for example testing.txt file
then, I get the byte array from that file.
then, from that byte array, I want to make a jpg file.

how to get byte array from file? and then make a jpg from byte array?

here my code:

```
//file to by array
$filename = "testing.txt"; 
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb"); 
$fsize = filesize($filename); 
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize); 
$byteArray = unpack("N*",$contents);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($byteArray); 
echo "</pre>";


// from byte array to jpg
$fp = fopen("result.jpg", "wb");
$len = count($byteArray);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++)
{
    $data = pack("C*",$byteArray[$i]);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
}
fclose($fp);
```

thanks

Comment: You seem to have the basics here: you have code for getting out the byte array, and are aware that `gd` is one of the main libraries for image manipulation in PHP (the other being ImageMagick). What is the actual problem you're stuck with?

Comment: actually my problem is how PHP convert a file to image and image to a file

Comment: Well, as I say, GD is a common library for doing that. You can find it in the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php It's up to you *what* you put in the image; you could draw a one-pixel dot for each byte, or a pattern of lines, or some crazy pattern. I'm not sure what an answer would look like other than writing the entire code for you.

Comment: I'll give you one free hint though: if you want a reversible operation, you probably want to avoid JPEG, as it uses "lossy compression" (approximates the image, rather than preserving every pixel). Use something "lossless" like PNG instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an code example how you can convert text data into binary one and then pass it to image. As mentioned in comments above, png is a better option of doing this.

```
<?php
const CHARS = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
    'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y',
    'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
    'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
    't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
    'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2',
    '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
    '8', '9', '+', '/'
];

function charToInt($char) {
    return array_search($char, CHARS);
}

function textToBin($content) {
    $content_len = strlen($content);
    $bin = '';

    // Convert content into binary
    for ($a = 0; $a < $content_len; $a++) {
        $bin .= sprintf("%06d", decbin(charToInt($content[$a])));
    }

    // Fill rest of last chunk with zeros as padding and calculate offset
    $offset = 8 - (strlen($bin) % 8);
    $bin .= str_repeat("0", $offset);

    // Return binary string
    return $bin;
}

function makeImage($textFilePath) {
    //get text data and encode it to binary
    $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($textFilePath));
    $binaryData = textToBin($data);

    //split binary data into 8 bit chunks
    $chunks = explode(" ", trim(chunk_split($binaryData, 8, " ")));

    // Add extra chunks to make total chuncks divisible by 3 for complete RGB pixels
    while (count($chunks) % 3 != 0) {
        $chunks[] = 0xFF;
    }
    // Calculate dimensions of image
    $dim = ceil(sqrt(count($chunks) / 3));
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($dim, ceil(count($chunks) / $dim / 3));
    $colors = array();

    // Convert groups of 3 chunks into pixels
    for ($a = 0; $a < count($chunks); $a += 3) {
        array_push($colors, imagecolorallocate($img, bindec($chunks[$a]), bindec($chunks[$a+1]), bindec($chunks[$a+2])));
    }

    // Set color for each pixel
    for ($j = 0; $j < $dim; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $dim; $i++) {
            @imagesetpixel($img, $i, $j, $colors[($j*$dim)+$i]);
        }
    }

    // Output image
    imagepng($img, 'output.png');
    imagedestroy($img);

}

makeImage($argv[1]);
```

Run `php test.php <path to text file>` to convert file and save it to `output.png`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide a text in an Image set up this two files:

**img.txt**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu vis assum mazim audiam, no everti recusabo mel. Facer hendrerit disputationi ei nam, ex nec vidit nonumes liberavisse. Oporteat qualisque eum id, vis semper vivendum vulputate at. Meis theophrastus vix in.
```

and

**img.php**

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * PHP Convert a Text-File to a PNG (and reverse)
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/51416394/5201919
 *
 * powered by adilbo.com
 *
 */

// HEADLINE TO BROWSER
echo '<pre><h1>PHP Convert a Text-File to a PNG (and reverse)</h1>';

// DEBUG INFOS TO BROWSER
echo '<h2>INPUT (img.txt)</h2><b>TEXT</b><br>';

// MAIN FUNCTION CALL TO WRITE TEXT TO IMAGE
$textInput = text2image( 'img.txt', 'img.png' );

// DEBUG INFOS TO BROWSER
echo $textInput . '<br><b>BINARY</b><br>';
echo implode( ' ', str_split( ascii2hex($textInput), 2) );
echo '<h2>OUTPUT (img.png)</h2>';
echo '<b>IMAGE (1x1 Pixel)</b><br>';
echo '<img border="1" src="img.png">';

// MAIN FUNCTION CALL TO GET TEXT FROM IMAGE
$textOutput = image2text( 'img.png' );

// DEBUG INFOS TO BROWSER
echo '<br><br><b>TEXT</b><br>' . $textOutput;
echo '<br><b>BINARY</b><br>';
echo implode( ' ', str_split( ascii2hex($textOutput), 2) );
echo '<br><br><b>"L o r e m" - Controll Values</b><br>';
echo strtoupper( dechex( ord( 'L' ) ) ) . ' ';
echo strtoupper( dechex( ord( 'o' ) ) ) . ' ';
echo strtoupper( dechex( ord( 'r' ) ) ) . ' ';
echo strtoupper( dechex( ord( 'e' ) ) ) . ' ';
echo strtoupper( dechex( ord( 'm' ) ) );

// HELPER FUNCTIONS
function ascii2hex( $ascii ) {

  // ini var
  $string = '';

  // loop string each digit
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < strlen( $ascii ) ; $i ++ ) {

    // convert ascii value to hex
    $byte = strtoupper( dechex( ord( substr( $ascii, $i, 1 ) ) ) );

    // add hex value two-digits
    $string .= str_repeat( '0', 2 - strlen( $byte ) ) . $byte;

  // end loop
  }

  // give back
  return $string;
}

function hex2ascii( $hex ) {

  // ini var
  $string = '';

  // loop string each two digits
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < strlen( $hex ) ; $i += 2 ) {

    // add each two digits hex2dec and then to ascii
    $string .= chr( hexdec( substr( $hex, $i, 2 ) ) );

  // end loop
  }

  // give back
  return $string;
}

function text2image( $textFilename, $imageFilename ) {

  // READ TEXT FILE TO STRING
  $string = file_get_contents( $textFilename );

  // OPEN PNG-IMAGE FOR WRITING DATA
  $fileHandl = fopen( $imageFilename, 'wb' );

  // WRITE PNG-IMAGE-PART
  fwrite( $fileHandl, hex2bin( '89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000000100000001010300000025db56ca00000003504c5445000000a77a3dda0000000174524e530040e6d8660000000a4944415408d76360000000020001e221bc330000000049454e44ae426082' ) );

  // WRITE CONVERTET DATA TO IMAGE FILE
  fwrite( $fileHandl, ascii2hex($string) );

  // CLOSE IMAGE FILE AFTER WRITING
  fclose( $fileHandl );

  // give back clear ascii text from file
  return $string;

}

function image2text( $imageFilename ) {

  // get image data (with offset of 95 chars for the PNG-Image Part)
  $binaryData = file_get_contents( 'img.png', FALSE, NULL, 95 );

  // convert data from hex to ascii string
  $text = hex2ascii( $binaryData );

  // give back
  return $text;

}
```

> It will generate a transparent 1x1 Pixel PNG Image named `img.png`
>   witch contain your text and you can also read the text from the image!

The Image is not so nice looking like from the answer from @DmytroZasiadko but also with a "read text from Image" function ;-)